# why cuda kernel can access host memory?

Tags: c++, cuda

I directly access the host mem in the cuda kernel, and found no error, why is this?

I tried to get smarter from the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gab84100ae1fa1b12eaca660207ef585b).

> Allocates size bytes of host memory that is page-locked and accessible to the device. The driver tracks the virtual memory ranges allocated with this function and automatically accelerates calls to functions such as cudaMemcpy*(). **Since the memory can be accessed directly by the device**, it can be read or written with much higher bandwidth than pageable memory obtained with functions such as malloc().

Why do many cuda programs add cudaMemcpy after cudaMallocHost?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define N 64

// cuda kernel access host mem a/b
__global__ void gpu(int *a, int *b, int *c_gpu) {
    int r = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int c = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;

    if (r < N && c < N) {
        c_gpu[r * N + c] = a[r * N + c] + b[r * N + c];
    }
}

// cpu function
void cpu(int *a, int *b, int *c_cpu) {
    for (int r = 0; r < N; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < N; c++) {
            c_cpu[r * N + c] = a[r * N + c] + b[r * N + c];
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int *a, *b, *c_cpu, *c_gpu, *c_gpu_cpu;
    size_t size = N * N * sizeof(int);

    cudaMallocHost(&a, size);
    cudaMallocHost(&b, size);
    cudaMallocHost(&c_cpu, size);
    cudaMallocHost(&c_gpu_cpu, size);
    cudaMalloc(&c_gpu, size);

    for (int r = 0; r < N; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < N; c++) {
            a[r * N + c] = r;
            b[r * N + c] = c;
            c_gpu_cpu[r * N + c] = 0;
            c_cpu[r * N + c] = 0;
        }
    }

    cpu(a, b, c_cpu);
    dim3 threads(16, 16, 1);
    dim3 blocks((N + threads.x - 1) / threads.x, (N + threads.y - 1) / threads.y, 1);

    gpu<<<blocks, threads>>>(a, b, c_gpu); // access cpu host mem
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();  
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    }
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaFreeHost(a);
    cudaFreeHost(b);
    cudaFreeHost(c_cpu);
    cudaFreeHost(c_gpu_cpu);
    cudaFree(c_gpu);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do many cuda programs add cudaMemcpy after cudaMallocHost?

Because many CUDA programs were written before the appearance of the unified memory system, and at that time `cudaMallocHost` allocated page locked memory. That page locked memory still requires an API call for copying. *"...accessed directly by the device"* means that the GPU can use DMA to read and write across the PCI express bus to the memory without the host memory manager needing to do anything, which is considerably faster than conventional pageable host memory.

As GPU and host architectures and operating systems evolved, it became possible for the GPU to directly access host memory on *some* systems through some GPU hardware and driver magic. That isn't universal though. The code you have posted won't run correctly on every CUDA system ever made, if it works correctly on yours (your error checking is deficient and it might not actually be working at all).